# How Union Works(background) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, union

I know the Union provides unique set of records of two or more tables. I would like to know how the SQL engine finds the distinct value when we use Union operator? In the background, whether if the value exist in first table then it will remove the second value from the result set?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not really clear what you are asking here. You seem to understand what is returned. Are you asking how the actual logic works? Not really sure what you are expecting as an answer here.

Comment: You can find that by displaying the execution plan for a query. You'll realize that what looks like a simple query can be quite complex, depending on whether there are indexes, whether the data needs sorting, the statistics of the tables etc.

Comment: Hi Sean/Panagiontis, Thank you for the quick reply. Yes i would like to know how the actual logic works, and I have checked with the execution plane where mentioned that the multiple tables concatenated but not understandable. could you please explain?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, of course, the next question is, how are operations like Hash Match and Nested Loop actually implemented. After every layer, you peel the next, eventually you get down to Solid State Physics and Quantum Mechanics. At some point, you eventually have to accept some axioms and accepting Godel's Incompleteness Theorems take some stuff for granted.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yes you are right i have to accept some Godel's Incompleteness. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways which SQL Server may *choose* to perform the `UNION` operation. Check out the list of [Physical Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/showplan-logical-and-physical-operators-reference?view=sql-server-2017)<sup>1</sup>. Note that `UNION` is mentioned as being done by either `Hash Match` or by `Merge Join`<sup>2</sup> and these two operators are quite different in their actions.

As a comment to your question stated, you can generate the execution plan for your query and see which operator SQL Server choose to use in your specific case.

---

<sup>1</sup>I've linked here because it's a good reference page for answering any "how *might* SQL Server process this bit of my query?" type questions. Many blogs have attempted over the years to determine which heuristics are being used by the optimizer to decide which specific operators to apply but of course the optimizer is always being improved and new operators can be added over time.

<sup>2</sup>`Concatenation` is also mentioned but that's only used for `UNION ALL` because it doesn't attempt to eliminate duplicates, so not relevant to this question as such.

Comment: Hi @Damien, Thank you for the reply, yes i referred  the link of Physical Operators, But still execution Plan showing that the concatenation operator used for the UNION operation.

Comment: Please refer this screen cast : https://www.screencast.com/t/qH6X9r4fw9

Comment: @SaranRaj - so there, it's performing effectively `UNION ALL` and then applying `DISTINCT` to that result (note the `Sort Distinct` afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a declarative language. You can consider its working similar to Union in C# list[Enumerable.Union(list1,list2)]

This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action.

COde will be something like these

```
   Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);

        foreach (TSource element in first)

            if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;

        foreach (TSource element in second)

            if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
```

CHeck out the below link if you want more of dot net code
[Enumerable Class](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs/%22Enumerable%20Class%22)

Comment: This isn't a question about LINQ. It's about *SQL* and how the server executes SQL commands

Comment: I don't think SQL server is written in LINQ.

Comment: This is sort-of how SQL Server implements a `UNION` if it picks a hash match to implement it, but only by analogy. It doesn't apply to merge joins, and it stops being accurate once we consider parallel processing.